# Why doesn't this AlertDialog.Builder.setIcon show the ic_menu_info icon?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The ic_menu_info icon is properly displayed in the xml menu item that calls it but not in this AlertDialog.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(menuInfo).setNeutralButton("OK",
 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int i) {
   // do nothing – it will close on its own
  }
 })
 .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_info).show();
 ...
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Needed a `.setTitle()` since that is where the icon wants to go.

---